# What commands show pending/scheduled tasks in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, gnome-terminal

What commands can I use in Terminal to see pending or scheduled tasks for today or tomorrow.

For example how can I detect pending system shutdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is util called `cron`. Usually `cron` handle task scheduling in Linux. But there is also few another ways to do it.

In case of `cron`, you can just run `crontab -l` to see all task scheduled by current user.

If you want to check task for another user use `-u $username` key

TO check `root` user tasks: `sudo crontab -u root -l`

To understand crontab format please read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab#Predefined_scheduling_definitions)

**If you want to detect exactly system shutdown**

The one of possible solutions is to wrap `shutdown` command in a script.

Another solution is to write a `trap` detecting SIGTERM signal, but this solution do not give you time when system will start halting.  Read about trap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832376/how-to-detect-pending-system-shutdown-on-linux)

Also there is another one tricky solution:

If you run `sudo shutdown -r 20:00`, you spawn a process that will start shutdown at 20:00.

You can find this process using `ps`

```
$ ps -ef | grep shutdown
root     32222 32032  0 15:55 pts/8    00:00:00 sudo shutdown -r 20:00
root     32223 32222  0 15:55 pts/8    00:00:00 shutdown -r 20:00
c0rp     32382 32233  0 15:55 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --color=auto shutdown
```

And you can see a time here. If you kill this process, shutdown will be canceled

Comment: thanks for the link to wiki documentation its helpful but for example I just run `sudo shutdown -r 20:00` for example and when I run any of your suggested commands it says `no crontab for root` so my question is how can I list command like that in case I forgot about that it was supposed to restart at 20:00 or any other hour.

Comment: Thank you! `ps` works just great :-)